# Use ActiveMQ JAR with an older broker

Tags: activemq-classic

In our production environment we use ActiveMQ 5.4.3

We encouter a problem since we added the option schedulerSupport="true" in the broker. The problem encountered is : javax.jms.JMSException: PageFile is not loaded

I recently discovered that this problem is fixed in the version 5.8

Would it be a problem to use the jar activemq-all-5.8.0.jar with that broker or do I have to upgrade the broker from 5.4.3 to 5.8 too ?

Thanks

Comment: The question is not very clear.  Are you asking if you can use older Broker to service newer client versions or what?

Comment: Ok, yes that's it, I'd like to know if a client with version 5.8 is supposed to work with a server 5.4.3 (any backward compatibility ?). In my case I have tried to upgrade only the client jar to 5.8 and to keep the server unchanged but then it took tomcat 1 hour to startup. So is it compulsory to always upgrade both client and server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommend that client and Broker use the same versions.  In theory you can mix versions as the underlying Openwire protocol is backwards compatible however it's not something we test heavily.  The usual case if that people can upgrade their Broker and need to leave client's behind and that is known to work better.  The problem with mixing versions is that there may be bug fixes in one that are necessary for the other to function correctly so you might still see bad behaviour even though you think it should improve things.